# How to use google cloud storage get_serving_url from remote php app

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I have:

- a Google Cloud Storage bucket with a load of images, which is uploading there using XML API automatically
- PHP-based website, too big to deploy and rebuild it on App Engine, situated on my own dedicated server.

Now I want to use the get_serving_url opportunity of GCS to get a sized image urls.

**UPD** [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) is not an option, because of phpseclib is not using mbstring.func_overload=2, which is critical due to Bitrix CMF I'm using

Is it possible? Is there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). This allows you to construct a URL which youy can give to clients which gives them permission to retrieve a file.

Even if you can't use google-api-php-client, perhps you can use [google-cloud-php](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/), which has a [`$object->signedUrl()`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.40.0/storage/storageobject?method=signedUrl) function.

If you can't use a library, there are manual instructions for creating a signed URL at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program.

Comment: I don't think that's what I need - signedUrl is just a way to give image url with access till date. But you can't use a signedUrl for image resize as it can be done with get_image_serving_url on appengine.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you need resized images.